# How do I retain my Start menu the way it is through the Windows 10 Anniversary Update?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I had the Anniversary update (build 1607) for a few weeks. Today, I had to do a clean install of Windows 10, and the boot media I had was of a pre-1607 build of Windows.

And holy bazookas the Start menu was SO much better before the update.

I just went through downloading updates, though, and I see Build 1607 in the 'waiting for restart' list. 
What I want to know is, what can I do, where can I find the Start menu files/settings/whatever to save/backup, such that I can go through the update, then "reinstall" the old Start menu. I'm going to try and put off restarting my PC until I find a solution, but Windows 10 has a way of forcing updates, so, timely help would be *much* appreciated.

Yes, yes, I've Googled this, and everyone says "You can't revert back to the old Start menu". But Classic Shell can change the way the Start menu looks, so it's obviously possible. Shame it only has...well...the "Classic" Start Menu as an option.

On that note, I'm also open to suggestions (unless its against the rules) for other third party apps that can do what I want.

---

EDIT: Please? Anybody? I haven't restarted my computer in 5 days x_x 
I'm just finding it extremely hard to believe that this is completely and utterly impossible to do. I've grown up with Windows, and I've never before come across an issue in the OS that wasn't user-fixable (provided the user was 'tech savvy' enough to know what he was doing).

Comment: What you want is not possible.  The only partial solution is to use something like Classic Shell but that solves an entirely different problem.  I suppose technically it is possible just not without third-party software, there isn't a huge demand for software, that keeps the start menu from Version 1511.

Comment: Do you know of any third party software besides Classic Shell that I could check out?

Comment: I am unable to suggest software here at Superuser.  I also never said the software exists, I hinted that the software does not exist, because there isn't anyone willing to make it.